# why wont this do while loop exit after accepting input

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, while-loop

Pretty straight forward. i dont understand why it wont quit the loop after not accepting a y char.

ive tried different variations of == and != with regards to y char and n char

```
vector<int> v;
    char ans;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter scores, enter number outside of 0-100 to stop:\n";
        get_scores(v);
        print_stats(v);
        cout << "Do you want to try another set of scores? Y/N: \n";
        cin >> ans;
    } while (ans != ('n' || 'N'));
```

after typing any char, the loop  keeps asking for more input.
NOTE: the get scores and print stats functions work as their supposed to.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Answers belong in the answer section

Answer (score 4):

Your comparison in the while condition is not correct, you probably meant to do

```cpp
while (ans != 'n' && ans != 'N');
```

`('n' || 'N')` will be coerced to true (1), so you would check for a char of value 1 instead of `'n'` / `'N'`

Answer (score 2):

```
    } while (ans != ('n' || 'N'));
```

Here you are comparing char with boolean result of || operation for the 2 other chars.
Which alway evaluates as true.
So your while statement is effecitvely

```
    } while (ans != true);
```

to fix this you need to compare ans to both of the n and N and exit if one of them becomes true, for example:

```
    } while ((ans != 'n') && (ans != 'N'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`while (ans != ('n' || 'N'))` is the same as writing `while (ans != (true))`. You probably wanted `while ((ans != 'n') && (ans != 'N'))`.